# in java concurrent programming, is need to using synchronized when read value?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrent-programming

this class can be used in multi thread because it is thread-safe.

```
public class Hello {
    private int value = 0;

    public synchronized int get() {
        return value;
    }

    public synchronized void set(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

i know that the reason that we must use synchronized when ***get()*** ,besides ***set()*** is memory visibility.

and java volatile keyword can be used for memory visibility.

so then.. this class is also thread-safe??

```
public class Hello {
    private volatile int value = 0;

    public int get() {
        return value;
    }

    public synchronized void set(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using AtomicInteger

Comment: BTW, I do not think that your first class is necessarily Threadsafe, you should Lock on an external Object

Comment: In this specific case, I believe `synchronized` is not required: 1. read/write of `int` in Java is guaranteed to be atomic (which is not for long/double/reference) for which they are the only 2 ways you are accessing `value`. 2. `volatile` guarantee for happen-before (which is another reason for `synchronized`)

Comment: we can use AtomicInteger but that is not the point of this question, i just want to know volatile can be used when read method, not synchronized.

Comment: @Adrian Shum, could i ask more detail for "2. volatile guarantee for happen-before"?

Comment: The question in your title is answered in the body of your question. Your *real* question is about `volatile`. Your second example would be thread-safe even without the synchronization. `volatile` does that.

Comment: @EJP: I think the **thread-safety** not because of `volatile`.  It is simply because he is getting value and assigning value which is an `int`, and such operation in `int` is atomic. `volatile` only helps for the happens-before/visibility part (well.... it is stilll kind of related to thread-safety... :P )

Comment: @SHRIN you may simply treat happens-before as an synonym for "memory visibility" you mentioned :P

Comment: @AdrianShum That's wrong. A write to an `int` is not guaranteed to be visible to other threads unless the writer *synchronizes-with* them.

Comment: @erickson that's what I said in the comment: that's related to memory visibility/happens-before.

Comment: In your second example `.set()` doesn't need to be `synchronized` either.

Comment: @AdrianShum Okay, I thought you were referring to example 1. I didn't notice he had synchronized the `set()` method in the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, you don't need that extra synchronized.  Given that you have already mentioned memory visibility (aka happens-before), I won't go deeper to explain this.

However, it does not apply generally.  There are several assumptions in your example making it enough to simply use `volatile`

1. Type of `value`

   <del>Although you are simply doing a simple retrieval/assignment of `value`, it is not always guaranteed to be atomic for all data type.  Iirc, Java only guarantee that such operation is atomic for `int` and types smaller that `int`.  Which means, for example, if `value` is of type `long`, even you have declared it with `volatile`, you may still corrupt `value` with your above example</del>
2. Operations on `value`

   Ok, let's assume it is an `int`.  In your example, you are simply getting and assigning an `int` for which the operation is atomic, hence simply using `volatile` is enough.  However if you have another method doing something like `value++`, using `volatile` is not sufficient.  In such case, you may either consider using `Atomic*` or use `synchronized`

---

Update: I later found that JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7 mentioned that using volatile would enforce atomic read/write on double/long.  So my original point 1 was actually wrong

Comment: thanks, the answer 2 is the what i want to know. just assign set() method make problem confused. anyway you say if method like value++ exists, get() method also need synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there's no need to use `synchronized` in neither the `get()` nor the `set` method, given the `value` attribute is declared with the `volatile` keyword.

This is because the `volatile` keyword forces a *happens-before* relation between writer and reader threads.

[Java Language Specification, Section 8.3.1.4. volatile fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4):

> The Java programming language allows threads to access shared variables (§17.1). As a rule, to ensure that shared variables are consistently and reliably updated, a thread should ensure that it has exclusive use of such variables by obtaining a lock that, conventionally, enforces mutual exclusion for those shared variables.
>
> The Java programming language provides a second mechanism, volatile fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes.
>
> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable (§17.4).

So, in your case, there's no need to synchronize the `get()` and `set()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Hello` there is only one field `int value`. Synchronized  locks whole object and thus heavy operation, Instead you can use AtomicInteger. Since Atomic* variables are faster. Volatile just satisfies "happens before" you cannot achieve atomicity for operations like "check then act" with volatiles.

To make `Hello` class thread-safe, the best way

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Hello {
    private AtomicInteger value;

    public int get() {
        return this.value.get();
    }

    public synchronized void set(int value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }
}
```

As  mentioned in [this post](http://nvcv22blog.wordpress.com/2016/04/16/thread-safety-with-locking/)

> If some object has only one field or its critical updates are
>   limited to only one field of object so instead of using
>   synchronization or other thread safe collections , Atomic variables
>   (AtlomicInteger, AtomicReference etc.) can be utilized.

Comment: non-blocking is not always better than blocking. `Synchronized` uses lock and so does `AtomicInteger` (assembly instruction - `lock cmpxchg`)

Comment: Hi. Yes AtomicInteger also uses lock but at very minute level. like synchronized internally uses monitor which is lock on whole object. In that sense AtomicInteger is better than synchronized.

Comment: so you might want to revisit this statement `Since Atomic* are lock free thus more efficient.`

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It would be nice if you can try to improve the answer.  If you wish.

Comment: There is one thing that Atomic* themselves aren't lock free but they make our code lock free if used.